# App installation tracking using AppsFlyer

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I want to track how my android app was installed by user, either by google play store or anything else. I've choosed AppsFlyer for tracking and referenced some sites and just coded to track app events alone and got it on AppsFlyer site too. But couldn't get that much clear about how to track whether its installed from Google PlayStore or any other media source like TapJoy or something else. Could u please suggest me any idea to proceed as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted? So that, it will be better to improve my questions.

Comment: have you find solution

Answer (score 3):

For AppsFlyer you need to implement their installation tracking - basically their broadcast receiver that catches the **INSTALL_REFERRER** intent (also set the appropriate permissions for your app).

https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android

And then put:

```
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().startTracking(this.getApplication(),"[Dev_Key]");
```

into your MainActivity "OnCreate" function.

That should be the minimum for tracking the installs.

Then you will have the option to use their OneLink "technology" to take advantage of deferred deep linking etc.

However their SDK is not the best documented one as well as it has some bugs so expect a bit of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Try  [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) or [Google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/)  both services provided by google.   easy to track installations in app data. if you like to track live data you should use google analytics. currently firebase doesn't have live feature.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your response. But i'm in need to use AppsFlyer only based on my requirement. So, can u please suggest me to proceed with AppFlyer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AppsFlyer has integrations with TapJoy, Facebook and 1800 other networks/services. You will be able to see for any install if it coming from TapJoy, Google Play Store or anywhere else.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your response. Do you mean to see the installation records in the site? But i want to track the details in code, so that if my app is downloaded from google play store, it should work as one way and if it is installed from any other media source, it should work in another way. So that, i need any sample code or idea to identify the installation type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appsflyer provide 2 type of installation tracking

1.Organic install-installation through google play store.
  2.Inorganic install -installation through other media like an external link,advertising api.

hope it helps.